# Rails, CoffeeScript and ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, ujs

So I'm messing around witha few javascript responders for a few actions. So, for instance,

```
def create
  #code omitted
  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      format.html { redirect_to discussion_posts_path(@post.discussion), notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
      format.js
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
    end
  end
end

#create.js.erb
$("#discussion_posts_table").append("<%= escape_javascript(render(@post)) %>");
$("#post_body").val("");
```

Now lets say I wanted to convert these javascript functions to Coffeescript (setting aside the fact that it gains almost nothing), if I change the file to `create.js.coffee.erb` it stops working. What's the proper way to use coffeescript in UJS?

For the record, I have `coffee-rails` in my Gemfile, and am using coffeescript in the asset pipeline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen .coffee.erb used before. Still looking around for that project.

Ok if they're still in your views, just use .js.coffee

Edit 1: Apparently Rails will still process the erb oddly enough.
Edit 2: Also, you can add erb to the end of a js.coffee file, they're jsut preprocessed in a particular order thus that might have thrown off Rails.

Comment: Huh. That's interesting. It does still process erb with no .erb extension. But now it's submitting the form twice. Hmm.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the [coffee-rails](https://github.com/rails/coffee-rails) gem to your project for this to work.

Comment: I do have the coffee-rails gem. Coffeescript works in the asset pipeline, just not at the view level