# UJS Create Action is making two posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, ujs

Okay, I have the following create action

```
  #posts_controller, nested resource under discussions
  def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])
    @post.user = current_user
    @post.discussion = Discussion.find(params[:discussion_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save!
        format.js
        format.html { redirect_to discussion_posts_path(@post.discussion), notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
      end
    end
  end
```

which comes off the following form

```
#index.html.erb#quick_reply
<%= simple_form_for [@discussion, @post], :remote => true do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :body, :input_html => {:class => 'span12 short_text_area' } %>
  <%= f.submit 'Post Reply', :class => 'btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

Kicking off this coffeescript

```
#create.js.coffee
$("#discussion_posts_table").append("<%= escape_javascript(render(@post)) %>");
$("#post_body").val("");
```

If I take `:remote => true` out of the form, everything works great, but putting it in makes two model objects instead of one.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong here?

Comment: `#create.js.coffee`? Are you sure? Not `#create.js.erb`?

Comment: Yup. Erb still evaluates event though it's not in the extension. Based doing so off of this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007498/rails-coffeescript-and-erb/11007588

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, as it turns out, was that I had precompiled assets in dev, which meant everything was in there twice.

Comment: Very familiar - had that situation too a while ago :)